# Can't import package android.support.v7.app (error: does not exist)

Tags: android, android-studio

I tried looking into topics that already are on this site, but I couldn't fix my problem based on that and neither did authors I think.

I am trying to `import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat`.

[Android Info p1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z9yU1.png)

[Android Info p2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2OJV.png)

I am new to this and I have been trying to get Android Studio to work, I am done with 1 project and after starting another I am stuck immediately with this:

> error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist

[build.gradle](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdTPA.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need to: `import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity`.

Use it in the class the requires it e.g. MainActivity.

You should also have e.g. : `implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'`

Comment: I am getting this now: "error: cannot find symbol class AppcompatActivity
"

Comment: What about the dependency, have you this: implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.0.2'

Comment: After correcting import line like @MartinZeitler I am back to "error: package android.support.v7.app does not exist"

Comment: @Pakuss you can either use the one or other; with that dependency the package name is `androidx.appcompat.app` instead of `android.support.v7.app`.

Comment: Resync the project and see the result.

Comment: Take out import android.support.v7.app.NotificationCompat;

Comment: Added code and build gradle in main post, I removed android.support.v7 and added something to gradle build. 
Only problem remaining is "import com.example.project2.R;"
I have 6 errors of type : "error: cannot find symbol variable ntext"
all of them are connected to that import. 
How do I fix this one?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to change any code, just add the `com.android.support` version:

```
implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0"
```

However, as @Will suggested, using `androidx` is rather the current way to do it. `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0` is alike `29.1.0` (which doesn't exist).